# drupal 8 template suggestions for table.html.twig

Tags: twig, drupal-8

I need to generate templates suggestions for table.html.twig and am not having any success. I tried to search google for an answer and found none. I also tried twig template suggester and it does not provide any suggestions.

Comment: Your question is lacking so much information. Could you be more specific? What have u tried so far? What is the output u'r looking for?

Comment: it is not lacking information. any drupal 8 themer will understand the issue perfectly well. there is nothing more for me to add.

Comment: Well if so, then I can only suggest migrating your post to [drupal.stackexchange.com](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

if you implement this function in your .theme file, it will allow you to add theme suggestions for your table

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_theme_suggestions_table_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables)
{
  $class = $variables['attributes']['class'][0];
  $suggestions[] = "table__" . str_replace("-", "_", $class);
}
```